# SQL rooms sold or available for series of dates

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are other posts about hotel booking systems on SO and I got some great ideas.  However, I am stuck on a SQL query.  What I would like is a query result for rooms sold.  It needs to have a row for each day and each room type in each day with the number of rooms sold.  For example, it would look this but with 0 for the missing room_types:

[image: results of query]

I have been able to create a query which will generate a series of dates and then count the rooms sold on each date.  If no rooms are sold of any room_type it provides a date line with NULLs in the remaining fields.  This is the query:

```
SELECT the_date::date, bookings.room_type, COUNT(bookings.id) as booked
FROM generate_series('2018-04-04'::date, '2019-04-04'::date, interval '1 day') the_date
LEFT JOIN (SELECT arrival_date, id, departure_date, room_type
        FROM bookings 
        WHERE cancelled IS NULL
        AND checked_out IS NULL)
        bookings
    ON the_date BETWEEN bookings.arrival_date AND (bookings.departure_date - INTERVAL '1 DAY')
GROUP BY the_date, bookings.room_type
ORDER BY the_date, bookings.room_type
```

My problem is, I need to show all the room types even if a particular room type does not have any reservations.  It should show the room type with 0 in the booked column.  I have a room_types table where the room_type is the primary key and room_type in bookings takes a foreign key.  I tried joining the room_types table in but I got incorrect data.

Bookings table looks like this:

[image: Layout of bookings table with example data]

Room_types table looks like this:

[image: Layout of room_types table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CROSS JOIN` like this

```
SELECT the_date::date, rt.room_type, COUNT(bookings.id) as booked
FROM generate_series('2018-04-04'::date, '2019-04-04'::date, interval '1 day') the_date
CROSS JOIN room_types rt
LEFT JOIN (SELECT arrival_date, id, departure_date, room_type
        FROM bookings 
        WHERE cancelled IS NULL
        AND checked_out IS NULL)
        bookings
    ON the_date BETWEEN bookings.arrival_date AND (bookings.departure_date - INTERVAL '1 DAY') and 
       bookings.room_type = rt.room_type
GROUP BY the_date, rt.room_type
ORDER BY the_date, rt.room_type
```